# Could the value of an html anchor tag be fetched using xpath?

Tags: java, xpath, html-parsing

If I have HTML that looks like:

```
<td class="blah">&nbs;<a href="http://.....">????</a>&nbsp;</td>
```

Could I get the ???? value using xpath?
What would it look like?

Comment: Your title is actually not what you are asking. It seems like what you really want is to fetch the contents of an `a` element that has an `href` attribute equal to a specific URL... is that correct?

Comment: I don't know about xpath, but a python HTML parser that's really nice is BeautifulSoup <http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/>. You're using Java, though, so this might not be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To use XPath you usually need XML not HTML, but some parsers (e.g. the one built into PHP) have a relaxed Mode which will parse most HTML, too.
If you want to find all `<a>` that are direct children of `<td class="blah">` the XPath you need is

```
//td[@class = 'blah']/a
or
//td[@class = 'blah']/a[@href = 'http://...']
```

(depending on whether you only want the one url or all urls)
This will give you a Set of Nodes. You'll need to iterate through it and then check for the `nodeType` of the `firstChild` (supposed to be a text node) and the number of child nodes (supposed to be 1). Then the `firstChild` will contain the ????

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use an XML parser to parse HTML? 
I would suggest using a dedicated Java HTML parser, there are many, but I haven't tried any myself.

As for your question, would it work, I suspect it will not work, you will get an error when trying to parse it as HTML right at `&nbs;` if not earlier.